# Samba - Two users for different access

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, samba

I have three harddrives and I want to have two permission groups:

```
Group1:
ShareDrive: Read / Write permission
TVDrive: Read permission
Personal drive: No Read / Write permission (ideally they can't even see it)

Group 2:
ShareDrive: Read / Write permission
TVDrive: Read / Write permission
Personal drive: Read / Write permission
```

Can anyone tell me how this should be done? Ideally I would have two users account but I can only work out how to set things up with a single user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is simply done by access rights in the filesystem... (except for the visibility)

OK, more detail:

```
ls /shares
ShareDrive TVDrive homes

chgrp Group1 /shares/ShareDrive /shares/TVDrive
chgrp Group2 /share/homes

chmod -R g=rX,o= /shares/ShareDrive /shares/TVDrive /share/homes

setfacl -R g:Group2:rwX /shares/ShareDrive /shares/TVDrive
setfacl -R -d g::rX,g:Group2:rwX,o:- /shares/ShareDrive /shares/TVDrive
```

If Group2 is not the primary GID of the users it may be useful to either do once `chmod -R g+S` or add `g:Group1:rX` to the setfacl -d.

Comment: A bit more detail would make this a mre useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `valid users` directive in samba's configuration file could help you achieve this.
http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html